# How can I figure out why two predictions from the same GLM have different compositions of predicted outcomes?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, gis

I'm creating a set of models predicting species presence and absence using binomial GLMs. I created a GLM model from some survey data, and I have made predictive maps for the current and future distributions of each species, with the predictors being rasters of present and future climate etc . Example:

Present
[image]

Future
[image]

There is a common pattern I've observed that I'm trying to understand. The present maps show a more even range of predicted values - you can see on the map that there are sizable patches with high probability of occurrence (green), moderate and low probability of occurrence (yellow and red), and no probability of occurrence (white).

However, if you look at the future map, the predicted values tend to be more extreme. They are most often either high probability (green), no probability (white). There are few of the moderate and low probability values (yellow and red).

Why would this be happening? I'm trying to figure out if this is a flaw in my model or an unavoidable consequence of predicting beyond the range of the values on which the model was originally developed.

Comment: It would help to know more about the data used in the model, e.g., what does *current*  mean? Is it based on predictions averaged across a window of time? The most recent period? And how did you structure the predictions for the future? How far ahead of the *present*, and so on?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the information requested in a previous comment, and also to present more details about the "binomial GLMs" that you performed and how their results are mapped onto the figures that you show. It's hard to know what might be going on without such details; there are many ways that binomial GLMs might go wrong. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted. Please include code and model output in your question with the `{}` tool on the toolbar, so that it's easy to read and copy.